# Click a button 10 times and reload the page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my code click a button and reload the page in Javascript. The button must be clicked 10 times every .5 seconds. When it's been clicked 10 times, I want the code to reload the page. Here's what I've got:

```
var rolls = 10

var q = 0
setInterval(
  function() {
    document.getElementById("roll").click();
    q += 1
  }, 500);

if (q == rolls) {
  location.reload(true)
}
```

Comment: Do you want the button to be clicked 10 times every 5 sec by itself and then reload the page?

Comment: I meant 0.5s, but yes, that's the general idea

Comment: `if` condition is defining `q` as `rolls` : `10`, not checking if `q` equals `rolls`

Comment: Fixed the typo, but it stil doesn't work

Comment: When is the button clicked? Any conditions?

Comment: Tresdin - the button's supposed to be clicked when q is less than rolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses `setInterval` to `click` on the button and decreases `rolls`. If `rolls` reaches 0, then the page is reloaded. Your mistake was that your code which checked for the value of `rolls` ran just after the `setInterval`, earlier than it actually became 0.

```
var rolls = 10;

setInterval(
  function() {
    if (!(rolls--)) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
    document.getElementById("roll").click();
  }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the checking into the setInterval method:

```
var rolls = 10

var q = 0
setInterval(
  function() {
  document.getElementById("roll").click();
  q += 1
    if (q == rolls) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're doing the check just at the time you define the interval, so

```
if (q == rolls) {
  location.reload(true)
}
```

is being called just once at the start.
put it inside the interval function like this:

```
setInterval(
  function() {
    document.getElementById("roll").click();
    if (++q >= rolls) location.reload(true)
  }, 500);
```